# Getting an [WinError 10057] in my python multiplayer game (using pygame)

Tags: python, sockets, networking, server, pygame

So I've been working on a space shooter time game with python and pygame, and hoped to use sockets and networking to add multiplayer capabilities in the game. The game isn't completely finished, and as I'm quite new to python (and even newer to sockets), my code isn't very elegant.

Whenever I run the server, this error pops up:

```
[WinError 10057] A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected and (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\Space_shooter(original_game)\server.py", line 3, in <module>
    from client import Ship
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\Space_shooter(original_game)\client.py", line 163, in <module>
    p.r = 0
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'r'
```

I think the last part `-- "has no attribute 'r'" --` is because of an error in either `server.py` or `network.py`, but I am not completely sure.

You can see the full code [here](https://github.com/Rshin2024/space_shooter)

(Disregard `test_game.py`)
Look into `server.py`, `network.py`, and `client.py`

Comment: You are getting an error in `network.Network.connect`, but since you have an `except: pass` statement, you don't know which. Never, *never* have a `except: pass` Statement anywhere. At least print the exception.

Comment: so would i do something like this instead:         except socket.error as e:
            print(e) (sorry if this is some really basic network programming -- I'm very new to this)

Comment: Okay, so I tried that and this error came up (along with the one in the question): [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Comment: You really need to remove all your `try` .. `except` statements. If the target refuses it, that means there is no server running. That probably means you are getting an exception somewhere in your `server.py` file and are suppressing it, or you are not even executing it.

Answer (score 0):

Looked at your code. In general if you want to get help, try to follow the guides in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). In other words, provide us with the minimum required code snippet that showcases the error, otherwise a lot of time is wasted in figuring out what the issue is. Also organising a GH repository like this is also not advised with all different artifacts in the same place, etc etc etc.

Now to your issue: It partly has to do with python and partly with sockets. You say you are new to both, so I will explain it in the most basic level possible.

**Python**

When you have a python code that **IS NOT** in a function itself or is not part of the special [**main**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html) function, this code will be executed immediately. I.e., if I have two files *a.py* and *b.py*:

```
#a.py

raise Exception("Some Exception")
```

and b.py

```
#b.py
import a

print("some code")
```

If I attempt to execute b.py I will not see "some code", instead I will see the "Some Exception" risen. Now, if I modify a.py to use the special **main** function or even if I put the exception raising in a function itself this problem will go away. I.e.,

a.py

```
#a.py (modified)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    raise Exception("Some Exception")
```

Now if I attempt to execute b.py, I will see the some code being printed.

**Sockets**

Now that you know this, we can see what the socket issue is. In your server.py you are importing the client script. Which will attempt to execute all code from line 118 onwards in client.py before moving onto the next import. In this part of your code you are trying to connect to the server. However, the server is not yet listening for incoming connections (even not created at this point) since you are doing this on line 16 from your server code.

In other words:

1. Avoid dumping code not belonging to a function in python.
2. Make sure your server is created **before** you attempt to connect a client to it.